# multiple router setup (Double NAT issue)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

I am attempting to set-up a network on a larger compound. The goal is to have two (2) individual wireless networks and a server connected to the first layer modem/router.

The modem receives internet access through a DSL DHCP MER subscription (no PPoE/PPoA invloved). Currently it is set-up with NAT and DHCP. The modem cannot be replaced. The modem's wireless capability is negated by its location, and so this is turned off.

The server is connected to the modem through LAN port 3 and has a static ip address.

One wireless network is set-up as an access-point (bridged mode), serving as a satellite for guests. It is connected through LAN port 2.

The main wireless network is connected through LAN port 1 to the router's WAN port. The router is an ASUS N56U. The router has a vpn functionality and this functionality is vital, and so the router cannot be set-up as an access-point. The issue is how to set-up this router. Since setting up a second dhcp/nat structure blocks the possibility of using DDNS for the VPN.

Additional information:

- There is only one IP-address going into the compound.
- Setting the modem in bridge mode will only let the main wireless network access internet.
- The modem is an Inteno x5668 device.

To repeat the issue. I need to set-up the main router so that I can access devices on its network through vpn (using DDNS). How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It would sound to me as if you need to open up some ports so that VPN server on your secondary router is accessible from your public IP, to do that - find the pots that you ned to use, and on your main router, direct those ports to the static IP of the secondary router.

> For PPTP:
>   TCP Port number=1723
>
> For L2TP:
>   UDP Port Number=500
>   UDP Port Number=4500
>
> For SSTP:
>   TCP Port number=443
>
> For IKEv2:
>   UDP Port Number=500
>   UDP Port Number=4500

Here are some common port bindings.

Comment: Thank you, I have already opened this port on my modem. The issue is that  the Asus router keeps telling me I have an invalid ip every time i try to set up DDNS on the router (I need the DDNS because my outward IP is dynamic).

Comment: Ahhhh, setup DDNS on the primary, not the secondary.
The secondary's IP address is on your intranet, so it has an internal IP, your DDNS host needs to know about your public IP.

Comment: And if you can't set up DDNS on the primary, there are services that will allow you to fetch your public IP address via a HTTP request, and some DDNS clients that can then use that data.